# Azure file storage/indexing solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm developing a Web Application, and it is running as an Azure Web App. This application has a section in which a user can navigate a directory, and allows the user to open the files and browse sub-directories in said directory.

At the moment, the sub-directories and files are inside `"~/Content/Documents"`, and I am browsing the directory's by using `Directory.GetFiles()` and `Directory.GetDirectories()`; functions which are provided by `System.IO`.

The files in question would be retrieved and downloaded several times a day, and there is no way to manually path one-by-one, seeing as there is a large quantity, and they are subject to change.

However, I has become inconvenient to store the files within the web directory. So my two questions are:

> What Azure service can I use to store and retrieve my files?

and

> Which of these services provides the ability to **index**/**map** a path, which would fit with my web-app?

Please note that the users **do not** have the ability to edit or otherwise upload any of the files, and there is therefor no need for the service to allow non-authenticated upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newish Azure File Storage feature can be used to store files in Azure Storage and make them accessible via an SMB file share. This will allow for legacy application that require the use of a traditional file share for saving / retrieving files. This allows for easier integration into existing applications without needing to completely rewrite the file storage code.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-file-storage-now-generally-available/

Comment: Thanks! I'll be looking into integrating SMB with my web app.